# Event for TreeView when nodes are removed or being added

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is there an event for `TreeView` control in winforms that can trigger when node(s) are being removed or added?

If no, how can I add an event myself to a TreeView?

Comment: No, the user has no way to add or remove nodes.  It is always done by your own code.  Since you wrote the code to add a node, you don't need to be reminded that you added a node.  You can raise your own event if necessary.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469072/create-an-event-handler-whenever-a-new-node-is-added-in-treeview

Comment: @Hans I agree that it should be controled from my side. The problem is I already wrote lots of code for my application, now I have the choises of going back and edit all the code where does something to treeview or make a new treeview with that events so I will just need to add a event handler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is, there is no all-encompassing way to accomplish this.

If you completely control the environment, you can create a class wrapper and make all clients call it's Add() methods.

However, most code works against the TreeNodeCollection - which you cannot replace.

So,
 `myTree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(...);`
or
 `myNode.Nodes.Add(...);`
or other paths like
 DataBinding...

will bypass a custom method.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview_events%28v=VS.90%29.aspx it would appear that there isn't a default EventHandle for the add/remove

So what you could do is write a custom treeView that inherits from Tree View.

Then you can have
Override Add -> Fire off your event handler

Comment: Wrong class, this is a Winforms question.  Otherwise correct.

Comment: Good answer +1, please edit the link to System.Windows.Forms.TreeView